# Changing font size and adding a label background in plot3D::text3D

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to change the font size of the `text3D` layer in the following plot:

[image]

As you can see, some of my bars are very dark while other are vary light, so I'd like to add a white background to my labels.

Reading through `?text3D` was not very helpful on this matter.

Thanks.